# How to set a video play to full-screen mode in a flash web site?

Tags: flash

In my flash site there is a video player that I want to have an option of switching into full-screen mode. It's the video player that needs to be set to full screen, not the whole stage. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`stage.fullScreenSourceRect`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#fullScreenSourceRect) property before changing to full screen mode:

```
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0,0,320,240);
```

That is the example given in the docs, but it will do what you want. Its a pretty neat function too as it enables hardware supported scaling if the users computer supports it.

Comment: things happen such as discussed at http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=191373

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML containing the Flash movie, you need to set allowFullScreen to true.

Then, within Flash, after a user clicks a button or presses a key you need to set stage.displaystate = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html

Comment: but i need only a part of the whole stage to fill the screen and that part is my video player. this is the question.